# Trying to add class to Element but there is not addClass

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

**Problem**

I am trying to add class to element in ShowError function. I found no such function to add class. Am I missing anything?

Below is the work done so far.

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6tbxc0eL/)**

**Html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="EmailAddress" class="col-md-5 control-label">Email Address</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {!! Form::text('EmailAddress', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("form#resetPasswordForm").validate({
    rules: {
        EmailAddress: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        EmailAddress: {
            required:   "{!! trans('Login.RequiredUserNameOrEmailAddress') !!}",
        }
    },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $.each(errorList, function(index, Message) {
            debugger;
            var Element = Message.element.parentElement.parentElement;
            //Trying to add class to Element but there is not addClass method
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the output you are getting from `Message.element.parentElement.parentElement;` ?

Comment: Top level div. Kindly check the html section in description.

Comment: Is there a way you can show the it via fiddle?because as you know adding a class is not a big issue, but i assume, the reult is not an HTML element or you are accessing wrongly via jQuery. the error is because you are not using addClass with an element

Comment: Added demo of jsfiddle

Comment: I think you can make it like this `$(Element).addClass("something")` right?

Comment: And I cannot make any error in your jsfiddle :(